# Customize fontfaces (such as \mathfrak{})

Tags: fonts

I would like to make take some existing fontface available in LaTeX, make my own modifications to a few letters, and then use this new customized font at selected sections in my document.

In particular, I am looking to make modifications to the standard font for `\mathfrak()`.

I imagined that I could locate the .ttf or .otf file, make some modifications, and somehow reload it under some new name. But I can't find any such files... In fact, I can't find any font-files that I can view (in Windows 10). I am using MiKTeX if that makes any difference.

Does anyone have some advice to at least get me started?

Comment: font design is off topic here really, if you are using pdflatex then you will not be using opentype or truetype fonts but type1 (postscript) fonts which are ultimately derived from metafont sources, designing a new font is not really something that can be handled in an answer here.

Comment: Look in the log-file of some document. The fonts used are listed at the end.

Comment: @david-carlisle I'm not asking about how to design fonts. I'm looking for some understanding how fonts are handled in LaTeX, in order to locate appropriate files (as a start).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks!! I was able to locate the file I wanted and convert it to a standardized oft format. That's a start.

Comment: If you are using standard latex fonts otf versions probably already exist

Comment: If you want to use opentype fonts I strongly recommend that you use xetex or luatex not tex or pdftex as the classic tex variants can not handle opentype font formats so it is _much more work_ to set up a font. with xetex or luatex if you have a font installed in your system, so word processors or browsers can use it then latex can use it just by calling it by name via the fontspec package.